# How can I plot a 2d vector field of a single ODE in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ode

I am trying to plot a vector field for the following ODE:

y' = -y/2 + (1/2)*e^(t/3)

I tried to do it with the following piece of code:

```
def f(y, t):
    dydt = -y/2 + pow(math.e, t/3)/2
    return dydt

y0 = 1
t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)

x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-6, 6, 50), np.linspace(-5, 5, 50))

U = np.ones(len(t))
V = integrate.odeint(f, y0, t)
N = np.sqrt(V**2+U**2)
Uf, Vf = U/N, V/N

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
q = ax.quiver(x, y, U, V, headwidth=1, headlength=3)
ax.quiverkey(q, X=0.3, Y=1.1, U=10, label='Quiver key, length = 10', labelpos='E')
ax.plot(t, (3/5)*pow(math.e, t/3) + (2/5)*pow(math.e, -t/2),'b-')
plt.show()
```

However, the result was awful and I even suspect it is wrong. The extra line there is a specific solution I plotted in order to see wheter my result was right or not and I do not think it actually is.

[Plot of a vector field of the said ODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWDny.jpg)

What is the right way to do this plot? I think I messed up with the 'angles' U, V, but I have no idea whatsoever how to solve it. Also, when I tried to normalize the angles, the result was even worse:

[Plot of the vector field with 'normalized' arrow lenghts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKScS.jpg)

**UPDATE**

I was able to solve the problem and found two methods of drawwing such a vector field. To be precise, the above method is mathematically correct, that is, the vector field will be given by: F = 1 î + y' j. With that, one can plot easily. I removed the normalization, as it gives an weird aspect. The code for that is just:

```
def gradient_method(x, y, y0, t, lim):

    u, v = 1, f(y, x)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.quiver(x, y, u, v)
    ax.grid()
    for i in y0:
        ax.plot(t, integrate.odeint(f, i, t), color='#5a28ff')
    ax.set_ylim(-lim, lim)
    ax.set_xlim(-lim, lim)
    ax.minorticks_on()
    ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
    ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
    ax.set_title('Vector Field')
    plt.show()
```

The for loop just draws some solutions with some initial states.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your plots. Your code has many errors when I run it. Do you mind updating it with working code? Also, one thing I noticed is that you may be **unintentionally doing integer division**. `(3/5)` will evaluate to `0` (in python2). You should use `(3/5.0)`, `(3.0/5)` or `(3.0/5.0)`. Same goes for the divisions in the ODE function.

Comment: `pow(math.e, t/3)` should better be `np.exp(t/3)`, it will be faster and slightly more accurate.